# How to make locust load scripts run in sequence?

Tags: performance, load, locust

I'm trying to automate the following scenario with locust:

1. Login to application (put it in `on_start`, so it will login all the sessions first) and get token value from response of login call.
2. Create an organization
3. Create a user.

I need these calls to be executed in the order shown.

However, if I add `@task` for the 2nd and 3rd steps, it will pick these calls randomly, which causes my code to break.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use Locust's [TaskSequence class](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#tasksequence-class):

```python
class SequentialTasks(TaskSequence):
    def on_start(self):
        # login to application and get token value from response of login call

    @seq_task(1) # the first thing to do
    @task(n) # do it n times
    def create_org(self):
        # create org

    @seq_task(2) # the second thing to do
    @task(n) # do it n times
    def create_user(self):
        # create user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it all in a single task. There is no limit to a single HTTP call within a single task (you could even put it all in `on_start` if you want to).

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        // do login
        self.token = ...

    @task
    def create_task(self):
        // create org
        self.client.post(...)
        // crete user
        self.client.pos(...)
```

Comment: If you do multiple things in a single task doesn't it mean there is no randomness between the requests inside - they happen immediately.

Comment: You can call self.sleep() in between the requests to achieve that.